# How are these pre-built search results page made, and are those considered black hat SEO?

Tags: seo, search-engines

I'm sure you've spotted search results in google that aren't really pages with content, but pre-built search result pages within the site itself. A few examples:

- http://www.indeed.cl/Empleos-de-Ingeniero-Comercial
- http://empleo.trovit.cl/trabajo-ingeniero-comercial

These come out first when you search "Trabajo Ingeniero Comercial" in Google. Their effectiveness in SEO is obvious.

Questions:
- Does this technique have a name?
- Are they generated dynamically with the Google search term, or are they pre-built and cached? And if they are dynamic, how is the search term retrieved?

I would love some insight in this technique.

Thanks

Comment: This is not the proper place for this question. This sort of question is better suited for [chat]. See [about Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

From a technical standpoint, the sites in question use rewrite rules or another catch-all technique to handle every URL on their site through dynamic scripts.   The software that powers their site is then free to show whatever it results it wants, including querying an internal search algorithm.

Google does not want pages of search results indexed in its own results.  Google's rationale is that the user is already on a search results page, why should they get another one when they click?   Google wants only pages that provide relevant content of their own in the SERPs.   As such, Google has defined the practice as black hat and has penalized sites for doing it.   Google recommends that any search results pages on your site be noindexed through robots.txt or a meta tag.